# Populating thymeleaf dropdown with data of another table and saving id

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have two tables: **Specialty** and **Doctor**. I need to populate a dropdown on newDoctor form with Specialties (Strings), but save on Doctor table the speciality_id (FK on Doctor table that references id (PK in Speciality table).

**ControllerDoctor:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/newDoctor", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String insert(Model model) throws SQLException
    {
        model.addAttribute("doctor", new Doctor());
        
        List<Specialty> specialties = SpecialtyDAO.getAll();
        model.addAttribute("specialties", specialties);
        
        return "doctors/newDoctor";
    }
```

**New Doctor form:**

```
...
<select th:field="*{speciality_id}">
                      <option value="">Select...</option>
                      <option th:each="speciality: ${specialties}" th:value="${speciality.id}" 
                      th:text="${speciality.name}" />
</select>   
...
```

Tryed this way but got this error:
*Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [int] for value 'null'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A null value cannot be assigned to a primitive type*

How can I solve it?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO, this site requires posts to be in ENGLISH language. I think there is a dedicated SO site that caters to your language

Comment: Oh my mystake, edited.

Comment: hello, when are you getting that error? when trying to save a new doctor? I think the error is occurring because you are saving the doctor without selecting a specialty and the field specialty_id in doctor is of type int.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select th:field="*{specialities}">
                  <option value="">Select...</option>
                  <option th:each="speciality: ${specialties}" th:value="${speciality.id}" 
                  th:text="${speciality.name}" />
```

you have to call the specialities  on th:field instead of th:field="*{speciality_id}"

i have mentioned the correct code on above